# can i force a client disconnect from the client

Tags: asp.net, signalr

SignalR determines client disconnect but it takes a while.. and I found it to be sometimes unreliable. For example I connected, disconnected, connected again and than disconnected again. The disconnect was fired two times at the same time (milliseconds difference).

Can I explicitly state that the client disconnected so that the event would fire instantly?

Comment: What version of SignalR are you using?